# Android Really can't BLINK(or FLASH) a button , it can only fade - Alpha Animation Set

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I found so many information about fading, also a blinking with static step like ON(500ms) -> OFF(500ms),  and yes, I have done both of it without any problems.

But the blinking animation I want looks like this

ON(15ms) -> OFF(150ms)->ON(15ms) -> OFF(150ms)->ON(15ms) -> OFF(300ms)->ON(50ms) -> OFF(60ms) -> LOOP forever

THINGS I DID

1.created the animation xml which should animate as I mentioned above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    >

    <!-- ON(15ms) then OFF(150ms) -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="15"
        android:startOffset="1"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="16"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="150"
        android:startOffset="17"
        />

    <!-- ON(15ms) then OFF(150ms) -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="167"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="15"
        android:startOffset="168"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="183"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="150"
        android:startOffset="184"
        />

    <!-- ON(15ms) then OFF(300ms) -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="334"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="15"
        android:startOffset="335"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="350"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="300"
        android:startOffset="351"
        />


    <!-- ON(50ms) then OFF(60ms) -->
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="651"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="50"
        android:startOffset="652"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="702"
        />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="60"
        android:startOffset="703"
        />
</set>
```

2. in the CLASS. I startAnimation when the button is at 'ON' State, and repeat the animation with onAnimationEnd.

   ```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        ToggleButton my_toggle;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       my_toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.my_toggle);
       my_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked) {
                   final Animation BLINKING = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.test_pattern);
                   my_toggle.startAnimation(BLINKING);
                   try {
                       make_animation_loop(BLINKING);
                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                   }
               }
           }
       });

   }

   /////////////////////////    FUNCTION INSIDE CLASS - PATTERN ANIMATION LOOP
   void make_animation_loop(final Animation BLINKING) throws IOException {
       BLINKING.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
               my_toggle.startAnimation(BLINKING);
           }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });
   }

   }
   ```
3. my Layout has only one toggle button.

   ```
   <ToggleButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="New ToggleButton"
       android:id="@+id/my_toggle"
       android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
       android:checked="false"
       android:background="#ff0000"
       android:visibility="visible"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
   ```

In my opinion, It should work fine. But when I run the app and click the toggle button. The toggle button just turns invisible.

Please help me.I workaround and been googling it for a week but really can not fix this.

THANKS IN VERY ADVANCED!!

Comment: Let me get this straight. The animation you've set does not work at all or does work but instead of fading in/out you want absolutely immediate blinking?

Comment: I think the reason for this is the duration of your animations. One millisecond seems pretty short for me :-P

Comment: @GeorgeD No, It doesn't work at all.  and yes, I want absolutely immediate blinking.

Comment: @IngoSchwarz  I workaround that and change it from 1 to 10ms (also change the startOffset to match). It gave me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have complicated this for no reason.

You want an animation to be repeated right?

1) Define properly the animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<!--This changes the alpha property of a View almost immediately (ie. this takes the faded object and makes it appear again-->
        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="1"/>
<!--This changes the alpha property of a View almost immediately (ie. this takes the object shown and makes it disappear -->
        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="1"/>
```

Now this is the animation that shows/hides an object immediately.
(These in fact are two animations in a set)

If you want the animation to run forever (or until you stop it) use 
`android:repeatCount=-1`

As for the delays (you mentioned that you want the button to be

> ON(15ms) then OFF(150ms)

that can be done by `AnimationListeners`. What you will do is set up a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) that works the best for you. And then you will set the delay by set start delay.

The [Property Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) is something you should take a look at so that you can implement this quickly and nicely.

Comment: Do I get it right? your idea is like, having animations that just ON or OFF immidiately. And I need to set the delay for any ON or OFF by the setStartDelay method?<br/>If so, still I can't find something like "setStartDelay" method in your document.<br/> Another thing, If I had the xml that you presented. How do I just call one of the alpha animations since there are two alpha animations within only one xml.

Comment: Yes. You can get each animation of the animation set with the AnimationSet class. Create an AnimationSet class by referencing the XML defined Set. Check the link belowto see how you can use the `android:startOffset` in your XML to make the animations stall a little and how you can get a reference to an animation created in XML from your code http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html.

Comment: I saw some useful clue with your link. gonna try it  and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

According to the suggested document  from @George D "http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html" I used the AnimatorSet with android:ordering="sequentially" and It fix my job.

Here is the code.

1.in res->animator->test_animator.xml

```
<set
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- 1 -->
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueFrom="0.0f"
            android:valueTo="1.0f"
            android:duration="1"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueFrom="1.0f"
            android:valueTo="1.0f"
            android:duration="15"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueFrom="1.0f"
            android:valueTo="0.0f"
            android:duration="1"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueFrom="0.0f"
            android:valueTo="0.0f"
            android:duration="300"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <!-- 2 -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="15"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="15"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="600"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.0f"
        android:duration="15"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.0f"
        android:valueTo="0.0f"
        android:duration="120"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

</set>
```

2. in the Class

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
       ToggleButton my_toggle;
       AnimatorSet my_animator_set;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       my_toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.my_toggle);
       my_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked) {
                   my_animator_set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this,R.animator.test_animator);
                   my_animator_set.setTarget(my_toggle);

                   my_animator_set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                           super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                           my_animator_set.start();
                       }

                   });
                   my_animator_set.start();
               }
   }
   ```

with the code above. it made the toggle button to blink

ON(15ms) -> OFF(300ms)->ON(15ms) -> OFF(300ms)->ON(15ms) -> OFF(600ms)->ON(15ms) -> OFF(120ms) -> LOOP forever